# How to fix unsafe implementation of HostnameVerifier

Tags: android, android-security

I have received this warning from Playstore because my code bellow is accepting all hosts

> You app is using an unsafe implementation of the HostnameVerifier. And refer a link to Google Play Help Center article for details regarding to fixing and deadline of vulnerability.

```
@SuppressLint("TrulyRandom")
private static void handleSSLHandshake() {
    try {
        TrustManager[] trustAllCerts = new TrustManager[]{new X509TrustManager() {
            public X509Certificate[] getAcceptedIssuers() {
                return new X509Certificate[0];
            }

            @Override
            public void checkClientTrusted(X509Certificate[] certs, String authType) {
            }

            @Override
            public void checkServerTrusted(X509Certificate[] certs, String authType) {
            }
        }};

        SSLContext sc = SSLContext.getInstance("SSL");
        sc.init(null, trustAllCerts, new SecureRandom());
        HttpsURLConnection.setDefaultSSLSocketFactory(sc.getSocketFactory());
        HttpsURLConnection.setDefaultHostnameVerifier(new HostnameVerifier() {
            @Override
            public boolean verify(String arg0, SSLSession arg1) {
                Log.i("hostname",""+arg0);
                return true;
            }
        });



    } catch (Exception ignored) {
    }
}
```

Now the problem is that I don't know how many hosts I need to add in addition to my main host.

when I tried to read hosts used in my app I found that they are many and they came from libraries ( Google ads , applovin , crashlytics , onesignal ...)

Here are examples :

> hostname: marcoasensiomadrid.website
>
> hostname: api.crashlytics.com
>
> hostname: ms.applovin.com
>
> hostname: d.applovin.com
>
> hostname: d.applovin.com
>
> hostname: rt.applovin.com
>
> hostname: a.applovin.com
>
> hostname: googleads.g.doubleclick.net
>
> hostname: res1.applovin.com
>
> hostname: onesignal.com
>
> hostname: pagead2.googleadservices.com
>
> hostname: onesignal.com
>
> hostname: api.crashlytics.com
>
> hostname: ms.applovin.com
>
> hostname: d.applovin.com
>
> hostname: d.applovin.com
>
> hostname: rt.applovin.com
>
> hostname: a.applovin.com
>
> hostname: googleads.g.doubleclick.net
>
> hostname: res1.applovin.com
>
> hostname: onesignal.com
>
> hostname: pagead2.googleadservices.com
>
> hostname: googleads.g.doubleclick.net
>
> hostname: googleads.g.doubleclick.net
>
> hostname: prod-a.applovin.com
>
> hostname: track.tenjin.io
>
> hostname: play.google.com
>
> hostname: play.google.com
>
> hostname: a.applovin.com
>
> hostname: res1.applovin.com
>
> hostname: res1.applovin.com
>
> hostname: res1.applovin.com
>
> hostname: pagead2.googleadservices.com
>
> hostname: pagead2.googleadservices.com

How can I Allow all Hosts used by my app and pass the warning at the same time ?

Comment: Why do you have this SSL bypass code in the first place?

Comment: @CommonsWare I am using Json and it seems like that I can't connect it to https url without the SSL bypass

Comment: You do not need to disable SSL to receive JSON from a Web server.

Answer (score 0):

Your custom verifier only works for ssl connections established via `HttpsURLConnection`; most of the third-party libraries will not be involved. At any rate, your problem seems to be that you need to allow some host that is not verified by default, not vice versa. In such case, the following code could help:

```
HttpsURLConnection.setDefaultHostnameVerifier(new HostnameVerifier() {
  private final HostnameVerifier systemHostnameVerifier = HttpsURLConnection.getDefaultHostnameVerifier();
  private final String hostWithSpecialCertificate = "marcoasensiomadrid.website";

  @Override
  public boolean verify(String hostname, SSLSession session) {
    if (hostWithSpecialCertificate.equalsIgnoreCase(hostname)) {
      X509Certificate certificate = (X509Certificate)(session.getPeerCertificates()[0]);
      final int ALT_DNS_NAME = 2;
      for (String altName : getSubjectAltNames(certificate, ALT_DNS_NAME)) {
        if (systemHostnameVerifier.verify(altName, session)) return true;
      }
      X500Principal principal = certificate.getSubjectX500Principal();
      return systemHostnameVerifier.verify(new DistinguishedNameParser(principal).findMostSpecific("cn"), session);
    }
    return systemHostnameVerifier.verify(hostname, session);
  }
});
```

<sup>this uses `private List<String> getSubjectAltNames(X509Certificate certificate, int type)` (copy verbatim from [OkHostnameVerifier.java](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/external/okhttp/+/322c9cf426a4b809b0b4bc3e739d878ab1dce6a5/okhttp/src/main/java/com/squareup/okhttp/internal/tls/OkHostnameVerifier.java#117)).</sup>